# Problem with use of logical operators in while loop in Kotlin

Tags: loops, kotlin, while-loop

I wanted to use && with while loop in Kotlin but it's not working. First, I generated 2 random numbers, then checked if they are more than 5 and if isn't generate new numbers until they're more than 5.

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){

    val rand = Random()
    var a:Int = rand.nextInt(10)
    var b:Int = rand.nextInt(10)
    
    while (a<5 && b<5){
        a = rand.nextInt(10)
        b = rand.nextInt(10)
    }
    
    println("a is "+a)
    println("b is "+b)
}
```

output is:

```
a is 1
b is 6
```

Comment: You want OR, not AND.

Comment: I want both numbers to be more than 5

Comment: you need to use logical OR for this `a<5 || b<5`, same with `&&`: `!(a >= 5 && b >= 5)`

Comment: Can you explain why AND is not working?

Comment: The condition with AND is to keep looping while both values are below five. As soon as one of the values becomes greater than five the condition is no longer true.

Comment: @IR42 is correct: you want a >= 5 && b >= 5. So you want to keep generating numbers when that is NOT the case. The boolean inverse of this expression is a<5 || b<5. In other words, if either one of those numbers is lower than 5, you want to keep generating numbers.

Comment: Yeah I got what you mean but I want both numbers more than 5. If I will use OR then even if one of them is less than 5, loop will stop right? So one of my numbers might be less than 5. But I need both of them more than 5. a>5 and b>5.

Comment: The condition given to the loop is not the same as you would use to check the expected result. You give the while-loop the opposite condition - the condition on which you got an unwanted result and it should be retried

Comment: Oh I got it now, thank you very much. One more question please, I also want to get two numbers where their division is whole number and of course divider is more than zero. So I wrote this loop:         while (a%b!=0 || b==0){
                a = rand.nextInt(10)
                b = rand.nextInt(10)
        } but a/b still gives me dividing by zero error. Why?

Comment: Swap the conditions.

Comment: That's working, thanks! Can you explain to me why reversing conditions solved the problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect logical condition. If you want both numbers to be more than 5 use condition `a<5 || b<5` in the `while` loop:

```
val rand = Random()
var a:Int = rand.nextInt(10)
var b:Int = rand.nextInt(10)

while (a < 5 || b < 5) {
    a = rand.nextInt(10)
    b = rand.nextInt(10)
}
```